# How to solve conflicting error of Attribute ActionbarSharelock and appcompat-v7

Tags: android, android-studio, attributes, actionbarsherlock

I got this error after i was replaced **ActionbarSharelock** library to **appcompat-v7**

I got error into build directory of values folder.

```
/media/ci-and-05/Project/AndroidStudio Project/1.40/src_logamp-1.40/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values/values.xml

Error:(174) Attribute "titleTextStyle" has already been defined
Error:(174) Attribute "subtitleTextStyle" has already been defined
Error:(174) Attribute "divider" has already been defined   
Error:(174) Attribute "background" has already been defined
Error:(174) Attribute "backgroundSplit" has already been defined   
error:(197) Attribute "navigationMode" has already been defined
Error:(197) Attribute "displayOptions" has already been defined
Error:(197) Attribute "title" has already been defined
Error:(197) Attribute "subtitle" has already been defined
Error:(197) Attribute "icon" has already been defined
Error:(197) Attribute "logo" has already been defined
```

This is my app.Gradle file

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.logamp"
        versionCode versionBuild
        versionName "${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

}

buildTypes {
    release {
        debuggable false
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

    }

}

repositories {
    maven { url "http://jzaccone.github.io/SlidingMenu-aar" }
    maven { url "http://mente.github.io/facebook-api-android-aar" }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/repo' }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.+'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.7.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp-integration:1.0.+'
    compile 'com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu:library:1.3@aar'
    compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:2.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.23'
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh:extra-abs:+'
    compile 'com.etsy.android.grid:library:1.0.5'
    compile 'com.github.filippudak.progresspieview:library:1.0.+'
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:1.5.0'
    compile('com.facebook:facebook-android-sdk:+@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.3.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.mobsandgeeks:android-saripaar:1.0.3'
}
```

I have removed all attr Attribute from values directory.
I have spend maximum time to solve this error.
Thank you.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/41243220/7235539