# Error:(254) Attribute "background" already defined with incompatible format

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-appcompat

In my old project i have use `roboguice-sherlock` and `actionbarsherlock`, now i also want to implement `com.android.support:appcompat-v7` and `com.android.support:design` but when i am trying to add this two dependencies in gradle i got this error given below.
I have also try to replace it but in some case it is compulsory to use `sherlock`

```
Error:(254) Attribute "background" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(130) Original attribute defined here.
Error:(481) Attribute "navigationMode" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(241) Original attribute defined here.
Error:(489) Attribute "displayOptions" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(247) Original attribute defined here.
Error:(502) Attribute "itemBackground" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(474) Original attribute defined here.
Error:(505) Attribute "actionBarSize" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(297) Original attribute defined here.
Error:(507) Attribute "windowMinWidthMajor" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(296) Original attribute defined here.
Error:(507) Attribute "windowMinWidthMinor" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(296) Original attribute defined here.
Error:(254) Attribute "background" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(130) Original attribute defined here.
Error:(481) Attribute "navigationMode" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(241) Original attribute defined here.
Error:(489) Attribute "displayOptions" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(247) Original attribute defined here.
Error:(502) Attribute "itemBackground" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(474) Original attribute defined here.
Error:(505) Attribute "actionBarSize" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(297) Original attribute defined here.
Error:(507) Attribute "windowMinWidthMajor" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(296) Original attribute defined here.
Error:(507) Attribute "windowMinWidthMinor" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(296) Original attribute defined here.
```

Comment: Don't use ActionBarSherlock, it's deprecated.

Comment: sorry to say later, that my project is old and now i want to add appcompat and material design. and i have also try to replace it but in some case it is compulsory to use sherlock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To replace *roboguice-sherlock* to *AppCompat* :

1). Remove all code which contain action bar

2). Download https://github.com/rtyley/roboguice-sherlock source code and put this packge **com.github.rtyley.android.sherlock** hard coded code in project

3). Remove dependencies :

```
1. compile 'com.github.rtyley:roboguice-sherlock:1.5'
2. compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0aar'
```

4). add dependencies :

```
1. compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
2. compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
```

5). Change some file *extandes to* in *roboguice-sherlock*

```
1. class SherlockAccountAuthenticatorActivity extends AppCompatActivity
2. class RoboSherlockActivity extends AppCompatActivity
3. class RoboSherlockFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity
4. class RoboSherlockListActivity extends ListActivity
5. class RoboSherlockPreferenceActivity extends PreferenceActivity
6. class RoboSherlockDialogFragment extends DialogFragment
7. class RoboSherlockFragment extends Fragment
8. class RoboSherlockListFragment extends ListFragment
```

6). AppCompat is ready. Now you can customise all in appCompat.

Comment: I am importing an old eclipse project into android studion and I got the same error. Is there any other way to correct it without changing source code ? my aim is to run the app on my device

Comment: @Rodrigo first try my answer step by step. If you get query then tell me.

Comment: I don't have permission to changes source code as you mentionned on the first step. i should just import it on android studio and run it without modification

Comment: @Rodrigo if you have to just import the code then it will import but it will not support `appcompat`. You can use only one at time either `action bar` or `appcompat`

Comment: What I have done, I import that `roboguice-sherlock` source code manually not with dependencies, so try that

Answer (score 2):

You are using `actionbarsherlock` which is `deprecated` and will cause build errors with the newest android build tools and support libraries.So,

Remove

```
compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
```

Add

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
```

Comment: sorry to say later, that my project is old and now i want to add appcompat and material design, and i have also try to replace it but in some case it is compulsory to use sherlock.

Comment: @PatelPinkal as your Project is previous made in `Android Studio` or `Eclipse`.

Comment: this project was made in **Android studio**

Comment: @PatelPinkal which case is it complesury can you specify.

Comment: @PatelPinkal as you can say your Project is too old so you have transfer that code into new one. because in that code there are lots amount of code now `Deprecated` so you have to convert it with the latest one.

Comment: In this cases i want compulsory

1). SherlockFragmentActivity
2). SherlockActivity
3). getSherlockActivity()
4). com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener()
5). m.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);

Comment: @PatelPinkal do one by one add `Style` change the `extend` Activity and also change the `deprecated` code.

Comment: i have alredy try to replace that but code become complected and getting so many error.

Comment: @PatelPinkal yes because other Activity that reference not work so you have to make new Project and tranfer all code with new one and all the changes.

Comment: Actually it is very huge project, so is there any way to implement in same project

Comment: @PatelPinkal you can tranfer in the same project but you have to do it very carefully and read the error and change made you have to do at your own risk.

Comment: If you get any kind of idea how to solve this problem please help me further. thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Don't use ActionBarSherlock, it's deprecated. Use support-lib instead.

Comment: sorry to say later, that my project is old and now i want to add appcompat and material design